# Typescript React.ComponentProps is not getting the props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

[image]

`boxProp` is not found in the `props`.

Library versions:

├─ react@16.13.1

└─ styled-components@5.2.1

Edit: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-germain-qunlz

Comment: It seems this is an issue in the types of styled components: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/52112

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because you aren't actually passing any props to your `Box` component, all that first line is doing is annotating WHICH props your `Box` component can consume - so React has no context of which props to extract when using the `ComponentProps` method.

Seeing as you are annotating the prop type yourself, an easy fix for this would be to do the following:

```
type BoxProps = { boxProp: boolean }

const Box = styled('div')<BoxProps>

const MyBox: React.FC<BoxProps> = ({ boxProp }) => {
  return (
    <Box boxProp={boxProp} />
  )
}
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation. This is what I was doing before, but I would like to infer the props

Comment: that won't be exposing the `styled.div` props which is what is wanted here

Answer (score 0):

Here goes my last attemp to solve this:

```
type OwnProps = { boxProps?: boolean };

const Box = styled.div<OwnProps>``;

type CustomBoxProps = StyledComponentProps<'div', DefaultTheme, OwnProps, never>;

export const MyBox: React.FC<CustomBoxProps> = (props) => {
  return (<Box {...props} />);
};
```

unfortunately `StyledComponentProps` has to be used. `React.ComponentProps` doesn't work well with styled-components interface. Definitely something wrong on their side.

Please let me know if that solves your problems, it should

Comment: you need to use these imports btw `import styled , { StyledComponentProps,  DefaultTheme } from 'styled-components';` just to make it more self-explanatory

Comment: I checked your codesandbox and my example works there, so it should be fine for your use case

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I may not know which styled element is behind ```Box```, that means ```'div'``` of  ```StyledComponentProps<'div'``` should not be hardcoded. Also If I use ```OwnProps```, I could just write ```const MyBox: React.FC<OwnProps>```. The whole point of using ```React.ComponentProps``` was to infer all of these types.

Comment: then you are probably not using the styled-components UI the ways it's mean to be. If it solves the issue can you upvote? as it's clearly a working solution